# Distribution of a variable with different uncertainties (statistical and systematic)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to generate the PDF of a measurement (M) to which I attribute a systematic uncertainty (dr). I tried two approaches which give me slightly different results:

- PDF(M) ~ Poisson(M) * Gaussian(M,dr) / M
- PDF(M) ~ Poisson(Gaussian(M,dr))

Which approach (if any) is more correct? If it is the second one, I'm also wondering how to estimate the variance? And/or for which conditions it can be approximated by the first one?

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: What is systematic uncertainty? Is M supposed to be an integer?

Comment: 'dr' is an uncertainty which is not random (e.g. calibration) and can be constrained via a Gaussian. 'M' is not necessarily an integer, but you can assume it isn't small (>=15), and that 'dr' is not too large (<= 0.2*M)

Comment: Why are you using poisson at all then? Is there a reason you want to represent M as an integer here?

Comment: The Poisson is to account for the statistical uncertainty on the measurement.
Say you count a number of events (M) -> statistical uncertainty; then apply a correction due to some systematic effect. To simplify, here I assume the correction doesn't change the number of events, but I still want to account for its uncertainty

Comment: It’s ok that M can be negative?

Comment: Not ideal, but its a very small probability. When it happens I set M to zero. You can take dr<=.15*M to avoid it